# Custom distutils commands

Tags: python, deployment, distutils

I have a library called "example" that I'm installing into my global site-packages directory.  However, I'd like to be able to install two versions, one for production and one for testing (I have a web application and other things that are versioned this way).

Is there a way to specify, say "python setup.py stage" that will not only install a different egg into site-packages, but also rename the module from "example" to "example_stage" or something similar?

If distutils cannot do this, is there any other tool that can?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, you can extend distutils with new commands.  In your distutil configuration file, add:

```
 [global]
 command-packages=foo.bar
```

this can be in `distutils.cfg` in the `distutils` package itself, `..pydistutils.cfg` in your home directory (no leading dot on Windows), or `setup.cfg` in the current directory.

Then you need a foo.bar package in your Python's site-packages directory.

Then in that package you add the classes implementing your new desired commands, such as `stage`, subclassing [distutils.cmd](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.cmd) -- the docs are weak, but there are plenty of examples since all the existing distutils commands are also built that way.

Comment: This answers the question asked, but virtualenv is a better answer to the problem.

Answer (score 56):

This can easily be done with distutils by subclassing **distutils.core.Command** inside of setup.py.

For example:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Command
import os, sys

class CleanCommand(Command):
    description = "custom clean command that forcefully removes dist/build directories"
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        self.cwd = None
    def finalize_options(self):
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
    def run(self):
        assert os.getcwd() == self.cwd, 'Must be in package root: %s' % self.cwd
        os.system('rm -rf ./build ./dist')
```

To enable the command you must reference it in setup():

```
setup(
     # stuff omitted for conciseness.
     cmdclass={
        'clean': CleanCommand
}
```

Note that you can override built-in commands this way too, such as what I did with 'clean'. (I didn't like how the built-in version left behind the 'dist' and 'build' directories.)

```
% python setup.py --help-commands | grep clean
  clean            custom clean command that forcefully removes dist/build dirs.
```

There are a number of conventions that are used:

- You specify any command-line arguments with **user_options**.
- You declare any variables you would use with the **initialize_options()** method, which is called after initialization to setup your custom namespace for the subclass.
- The **finalize_options()** method is called right before **run()**.
- The guts of the command itself will occur in **run()** so be sure to do any other prep work before that.

The best example to use is just to look at the source code for one of the default commands found at *PYTHON_DIR/distutils/command* such as *install.py* or *build.py*.

Comment: Use [the sources](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/9d88b4875d6e12570a635848524bb7f5283ee558/lib-python/2.7/distutils/command?at=translation-cleanup), Luke.

Comment: And [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#creating-a-new-distutils-command).

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to use multiple version then [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) with [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) can help.

Answer (score 2):

See [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710839/custom-distutils-commands/1712268#1712268) if you want a way to do this with distutils, but I find [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/) to be better for this kind of thing.  It makes it a lot easier to make custom commands or override existing ones.  Plus the transition isn't terribly difficult if you're used to distutils or setuptools.

Comment: Paver provides a lot of interesting handy functionalities and shortcuts. On the other hand, it adds another paradigm (and architecture) on top of distutils. I would prefer a plain setup.py file which is self-contained and does everything which needs to be done.