# How do I add a custom build step to my setuptools / distribute setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

I would like to call the C compiler from my `setup.py` by using platformer instead of Extension(). How do I add a custom build step to `setup.py` so that it is run with `python setup.py build` or any of the other build (`bdist_*`) commands?

Comment: related: [Custom distutils commands](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1710839/4279)

Comment: Today I'd solve this problem by replacing setuptools entirely with a PEP 517 compatible build system. Flit, poetry, https://pypi.org/project/enscons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what 'platformer' is. I assume that you want a complete control over how C extensions are built while providing the same interface for packaging tools.

A possible way: [Cython defines its custom built_ext command](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py) that [could be used as](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("example", ["example.pyx"])]
)
```

A simpler option might be just to include generated C sources into your source tarball and use standard built_ext, Extension classes in setup.py. It would provide the best compatibility with existing tools.